# After logout pressing the browser back button it redirects to previous page

Tags: php

After Logout, it goes to login page but when I press back button from browser it goes to the previous page that is not properly login. But I try that after logout until login user cannot access the pages.

I want that after logout when user press back button it goes all times to login page. But in my code there after logout pressing back button it goes to the back page and user can access pages after logout.

I am a beginner in PHP. Please help me out.

login.php

```
<?php
session_destroy();
session_start();
$message="";
if(count($_POST)>0) {
 $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','db name') or die('Unable To connect');
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");
$row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(is_array($row)) {
$_SESSION["id"] = $row[id];
$_SESSION["username"] = $row[username];
{
if (isset($_POST["username"]) AND $_POST["username"] == 'moyna') {
header("Location:welcomemoyna.html");
}
elseif(isset($_POST["username"]) AND $_POST["username"] == 'ramtarak') {
header("Location:welcomeramtarak.html");
}
elseif(isset($_POST["username"]) AND $_POST["username"] == 'tamluk') {
header("Location:welcometamluk.html");
}
elseif(isset($_POST["username"]) AND $_POST["username"] == 'bagnan') {
header("Location:welcomebagnan.html");
}
elseif(isset($_POST["username"]) AND $_POST["username"] == 'admin') {
header("Location:welcomeadmin.html");
}
elseif(isset($_POST["username"]) AND $_POST["username"] == 'quickd') {
header("Location:welcomequickd.html");
}
}
}
else {
$message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
}
// }
}
?>
<?php
// remove all session variables
session_unset(); 

// destroy the session 
session_destroy();

echo "All session variables are now removed, and the session is destroyed." 
?>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <title>Quick Group</title>
     BOOTSTRAP CORE STYLE CSS 
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     FONT AWESOME CSS 
<link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      FLEXSLIDER CSS 
<link href="assets/css/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     CUSTOM STYLE CSS 
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
   Google   Fonts 
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

<title>User Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top " id="menu">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">QUICK GROUP</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse move-me">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li ><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">FEATURES</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">COURSES</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                     <li><a href="login.php">LOGIN</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="" align="center">
<div class="message"><?php if($message!="") { echo $message; } ?></div>
<h3 align="center">Enter Login Details</h3>
 Username:<br>
 <input type="text" name="username">
 <br>
 Password:<br>
<input type="password" name="password">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset">
</form>
<center>
<a href="passwordchange.php">Change password</a>
<!--<a href="newexpenseview.php">Change password</a>-->
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION["id"]);
unset($_SESSION["username"]);
header("Location:login.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing this in php will need you to :

> set a check on each page whether the user is logged in or not using variable to denote the logged in state, if not
>   then user should get redirected back to login page.

```
<?php 
  if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) : 
  header("Location: loginPage.php");  ?>
```

then, on logout, you need to unset the logged in status variable & destroy the session, by virtue of which if the user now presses back the logged in status variable will not be found and the page doesn't load.

```
<?php
  unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);  
  session_destroy();  ?>
```

*--Thanks for asking.*